# Powershell where-object | get-date

Tags: powershell

Hello i want to get only the month and year of a file with Date context
for example:

```
Where-Object {$_.StartDate-eq (Get-Date).AddDays(0).ToString("mm.yyyy") } |
```

current status:

```
 Get-Content "file" -Encoding:String | 
Select -Skip 1 | 
ConvertFrom-Csv |
Where-Object {$_.StartDate -eq (Get-Date).ToString("MM.yyyy") } |
Where-Object {-not $_.DestinationNumber.StartsWith("+49") -and $_.DestinationNumber.StartsWith("+")} |
ForEach { [DateTime]$_.EndTime - [DateTime]$_.StartTime } |
ForEach { $Total=0 } { $Total += $_.TotalMinutes}
[math]::Round($Total,2),'Minuten'
```

i hope any body can help me.

Comment: What is `$_.StartDate`? A string? A DateTime object?

Comment: Yeah as mathias said, what type is $_.StartDate ? Can you post a sample value of it ?

Comment: yes: 
$_.StartDate = 13.02.2014

Answer (score 2):

Lower Case 'm' denotes minutes, you will have to use upper case M for month. Something like..

```
{$_.StartDate-eq (Get-Date).AddDays(0).ToString("MM.yyyy")
```

You don't need to invoke AddDays method, if u just have to get the current date. You can simple try,

```
(Get-Date).ToString("MM.yyyy")
```

**--EDIT as per OP Clarification--**

From the context it appears that you want to convert `$_.StartDate` to **MM.yyyy** format. If that's the case *(assuming you have a valid date time value in $_.StartDate)* you can use the Get-Date method on it. Something like,

```
Where-Object {(Get-Date($_.StartDate)).ToString("MM.yyyy") -eq (Get-Date).ToString("MM.yyyy") }
```

Comment: no sorry i explained bad. 

the date in the file is in dd.mm.yyyy format. But i need for the input only mm.yyyy
I hope you understand me now.

Thanks

Comment: @mertrin1ty don't post code in comments, please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41750308/edit) your original question instead

Comment: @Prageeth Saravanan i did